# How to move caption on the left with multiple row picture insertion

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

I want to have a layout of pic and caption as following
[image]

I try to use subfigure with minpage to realize it,but falied and hope someone can help me.
here is my code(I use ieee_conference template)(learn frome

```
\begin{figure*}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy}
                \label{fig:dummy}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{First}
        \label{subfig-1:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Second}
        \label{subfig-2:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Third}
        \label{subfig-3:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Fourth}
        \label{subfig-4:dummy}
    \end{subfigure} 

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height = 0.15\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Fifth}
        \label{subfig-5:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}

\end{figure*}
```

[image: my code generate]

My ideal result simalar with my drawing above is that the caption is on left sizd and start parallel with the first row, and the rectange picure on the seconde row is aligned with four small pictures on the first row.

Comment: Well, please show us the code you have tried. We missinformations about used documentclass and perhaps packages which you have to use ...  BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Hey bro, I have updated my question with code and pic.Can you give me some tips?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: And please don't call us bro and don't be impatient... Here people try to help each other, as far as they can ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I will check the starter guide.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an empty `minipage` before the last image:

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\end{minipage}
```

and the result is:

[image]

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy}
                \label{fig:dummy}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{First}
        \label{subfig-1:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Second}
        \label{subfig-2:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Third}
        \label{subfig-3:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Fourth}
        \label{subfig-4:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.675\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height = 0.15\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Fifth}
        \label{subfig-5:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

---

### EDIT

In response to your comment, probably you want something like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.35\linewidth}
                \caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy}
                \label{fig:dummy}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.22\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{First}
        \label{subfig-1:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.22\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Second}
        \label{subfig-2:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.22\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Third}
        \label{subfig-3:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.22\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Fourth}
        \label{subfig-4:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height = 0.15\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Fifth}
        \label{subfig-5:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you.But I want to make the caption cover two row on the leftside,your method is similar with moving a space block on the left of the rectangel picture.

Comment: @user3219735 See if the code in the edit fits your needs.

Comment: Not that it changes much, but you should have `%` at the end of every line preceding `\hfill`, or a normal space is added. In this case it doesn't really matter, but if you change 0.35 and 0.6 to be something with sum nearer to 1, this space could move the second minipage on the next line. I'd write `\end{minipage}\hfill` and `\end{subfigure}\hfill`.

Comment: @egreg You're perfectly right.